# SIFT keypoint detection in Matlab

Tags: computer-vision, sift

I am currently working on SIFT using Matlab. I had implemented the Scale-Space and DoG. Currently working on Keypoint localization. I am able to extract the maxima and minima. How should I proceed from here? Besides that, anyone is interest to verify my coding?

Comment: This site is not designed to review/verify other people's code.  It is designed to answer technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ipol.im/pub/pre/82/preprint.pdf . This paper gives a detailed analysis of SIFT . This should clarify most of your implementation based queries

Comment: Oops just realized that this question is pretty old. Good luck anyway !